# About FoneMonkey

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, automation, fonemonkey

Can anyone tell me the advantages and *disadvantages* of **FoneMonkey**? And also I need all the list of possible components that can be tested.(Fonemonkey command reference is not the complete list).
   Please help me on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get some useful info at http://www.gorillalogic.com/fonemonkey
all the best

Comment: you can check it also http://www.mobileapptesting.com/fonemonkey-5-open-source-testing-tool-for-iphone-ipad/2011/04/

Comment: Thanks Manoj, But I dont want info about FoneMonkey I want the supported components. They are not completely listed in their website and not possible to get it in web. If you're an iphone developer and if you used fonemonkey, tell me the components you worked on. That'll be helpful. Thank you